# MySQL: tinyint(1) vs. enum('1','2','3')

Tags: база-данных, mysql

Есть поле, которое может принимать 3 значения.

Что лучше использовать с точки зрения производительности?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

enum хранится как число
если необходимо хранить данные от 1 до 3, то разницы нет :)

В любом случае в производительности вы ничего не выигрываете и не теряете. Используйте tinyint если храните именно числа, т.к. в enum хранить числа не рекомендуется :)